# Converting C formula to C#

Tags: c#, c

I'm trying to convert the line below to C#. Dik and eint and ratio are variables. I'm unsure how to represent &a in c# and modf if I can get guidance please and thank you.

```
(void) modf (ratio * (dik / eint), &a);
```

Comment: What are the data types for `ratio`, `dik`, `eint`, and `a`?

Comment: They are double values. A is an INt*

Comment: @user3276954 In that case, your C is messed up too ;)  `a` should be defined as a `double` for modf: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/modf/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm unsure how to represent &a in c# and modf if I can get guidance please and thank you.

You can use [`Math.Truncate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2eabd70%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in C#:

```
double a = Math.Truncate(ratio * dik / eint);
```

This will return "the integral part of a specified double-precision floating-point number", which is the same value returned in [modf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/modf/)'s `intpart` parameter (your `&a`).

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
   double a = (int) (ratio * (dik / eint)); // Integer portion

   double x = (ratio * (dik / eint)) % 1;  // Fractional portion
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the address of a variable in C# just like you do in C.

```
int* apointer = &a
```

Will give you the address in memory of the variable a.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcbcf4ta.aspx

Comment: ...In an unsafe context, after enabling the compiler flag.

Comment: Under unsafe .. but *why* (here)?